# Is it possible to create a quiz app, with levels, without a game engine?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

The main reason for asking this question is to find a way to do it without having to create 50 classes/layouts for 50 levels.

I've looked over some source code for a quiz app that doesn't use levels and I've gained a better understand on how it's done. They've used an SQLite database to randomly pull 10 questions from a table of 70 and then it gives you a score at the end.

Can I implement an SQLite database in a similar fashion, but each question has its own level? Then of course completing one level opens the next and so on.

This is my first foray into the game side of Android, I've released other applications so I have a fair bit of general android knowledge. If I need 50 classes then I might as well store the questions in strings.xml.

The whole SQLite thing looks quite complicated but if I do come into trouble I have source code to refer to, so hopefully it's something that can be done.

Of course if I do need a game engine then I can always start on that with AndEngine, just need to understand the direction to take.

Would really appreciate some advice on it, thank you.

Comment: Just add a level column to the question table and filter your query results by that.

Comment: Thanks, so the database way is possible. Could you offer a bit more advice in regards to generating the levels? I mean the main page will have 50 buttons and, if a user clicks on say 27 is it as simple as running an if statement? I'll continue to look into SQLite a bit more now.

Comment: Just have your buttons `onClick` set the level. If the user clicks on button 27 you pass level=27 as the argument for your query when loading the questions.

Comment: Crap should have thought of that. Thanks! Chuck it an answer and I'll mark it as the official answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a level column to the question table and filter your query results by that. Have your buttons onClick set the level for the questions you want. If the user clicks on button 27 you pass level=27 as the argument for your query when loading the questions.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways but the simplest is make every new level on button click.
make a screen containing level buttons and on clearing every other level user switched to new one just on a click.